Flask file manager
Looking for a Flask-based file manager to integrate into a larger Flask project. Don't want to be reinventing the wheel, so looking for something that is mature enough and easy to integrate. Any recommendations are welcome.
Must have:

Permissive license (not copyleft)
Ability to browse directories and files
Ability to upload files
Ability to delete files
Ability to delete directories recursively

Good to have:

Integration using Flask Blueprint would be great
Locking root directory outside of which user cannot browse would be a major bonus
Drag and drop uploads would be a nice feature
Uplading directories would be cool, but not high on priority list
Breadcrubs for easy navigation are a bonus
Decent CSS theme

What I have considered so far in order of preference:
Candidate 1:
https://pypi.org/project/flask-file-explorer/
pros: Lightweight, Blueprints, Extremely intuitive
cons: Deleting files not supported (major), visuals are rather basic (minor)
Candidate 2:
https://github.com/reallyrehan/flask-fileexplorer
pros: Intuitive, Beautiful design
cons: Integration will be hard work (no Blueprints), Deleting files not supported (major), Heavy (large repo size)
